# Random images and text with query mobile

Tags: jquery, arrays, mobile, random

I have some code that I am using to generate a random image when the initial screen image is clicked (found on JavascriptSource):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Original: Nicholas Lupien-->
<!-- Begin
var rand1 = 0;
var useRand = 0;

images = new Array;
images[1] = new Image();`
images[1].src = "../../Myimages/images/01.png";
images[2] = new Image();
images[2].src = "../../Myimages/images/02.png";
images[3] = new Image();
images[3].src = "../../Myimages/images/03.png";
images[4] = new Image();
images[4].src = "../../Myimages/images/04.png";
images[5] = new Image();
images[5].src = "../../Myimages/images/05.png";
images[6] = new Image();
images[6].src = "../../Myimages/images/06.png";

   function swapPic() {
   var imgnum = images.length - 1;
    do {
      var randnum = Math.random();
      rand1 = Math.round((imgnum - 1) * randnum) + 1;
        } while (rand1 == useRand);
          useRand = rand1;
          document.randimg.src = images[useRand].src;
          }
// End -->
</script>
```

*This part of the code works fine:* the user taps the image and the image changes to another random image in the array.

**However, I'd like to add a descriptive text so that the image would be generated with the text.** I don't know how to match the text with the correct image and get it to randomly generate along with the image. I'm using Jquery Mobile.

**Steps:**

*1. User taps initial random image (text description from separate array ??) on device.*

*2. User sees a random image with a descriptive text.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want an element to put the description in, and also to store the descriptions. I've cut down your code slightly for example purposes, but the logic is the same:

```
var rand1 = 0;
var useRand = 0;

var descriptions = [];
images = new Array;
images[1] = new Image();
images[1].src = "../../Myimages/images/01.png";
descriptions[1] = 'This is a description';
images[2] = new Image();
images[2].src = "../../Myimages/images/02.png";
descriptions[2] = 'This is another description';

var descriptionHolder = document.getElementById('description_holder');


function swapPic() {
    var imgnum = images.length - 1;
    do {
        var randnum = Math.random();
        rand1 = Math.round((imgnum - 1) * randnum) + 1;
    }while (rand1 == useRand);
    useRand = rand1;
    document.randimg.src = images[useRand].src;
    descriptionHolder.innerHTML = descriptions[useRand];
}
```

For this, a new element has been added to the page that has an id of `description_holder`.

Comment: Michael: That got it and helped me to learn something along the way. Thank you for taking the time to show me how this is done. Next on my list is learning how to populate this array with a local json file, but that is another question. Thanks again for your help. -Rachel

Comment: No problem. Please be sure to accept this as the answer to help future people.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the alt (or title) attribute:

```
images[1].alt = "text of image";
```